# Who wins the following hand

Tags: texas-hold-em, hand

Which hand would win in Texas Hold-em?
Community Cards 9,10,K,A,A.
P#1 Hole Cards 10,K.
P#2 Hole Cards  J,K

Answer (score 2):

The player who can form the best five card combination with the community cards and his hole cards win.

Player 1 has two pair: 10, K, K, A, A

Player 2 also has two pair: J, K, K, A, A

But player 2 has a better kicker, his jack plays. His KJ pushed out the 9 and 10 from the community cards. Player 1 can only replace the 9 from the community cards with his K. The ten does not matter, same value.

(assuming flushes are not in play here).

Comment: Thank you very much. This makes it very clear. Thank you for your response.